# Rsync makes the destination folder unwritable before copying files to it (and then of course it fails with Permission Denied)

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync, file-permissions

I want to use rsync to deploy a project from my dev machine (Windows 11, CygWin) to a remote server (Ubuntu) through SSH. I've made sure that my SSH user has full write access to the destination folder by running the commands below:

```
root# mkdir /opt/my-project
root# chmod +rwx /opt/my-project
root# cwown -R ubuntu /opt/my-project
ubuntu$ touch /opt/my-project/test && rm /opt/my-project   # No errors
```

On my Windows machine, I am using the following rsync command:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\rsync.exe -Pav \
    -e "C:/cygwin64/bin/ssh.exe -i <SSH Key File>" \
    ./bin/Release/net6.0/linux-x64/publish/ ubuntu@my_server:/opt/my-project/
```

I would expect this command to start an incremental file synchronization, and upload all the missing files to the project folder on the server. But instead, the rsync tool spits out a bunch of `Permission denied (13)` errors and fails to copy a single file. On top of that, when I go back to the server to check the target folder, the `ubuntu` user no longer has any form of access to it. Even listing the folder (`ls /opt/my-project`) gives a Permission denied error.

This is a very strange behavior, because prior to the upload, the `ubuntu` user definitely has full write access to the target folder, but it seems like rsync intentionally locks itself out of the folder before transferring a single file.

Here's the shortened output of the rsync command:

```
sending incremental file list
rsync: failed to modify permissions on "/opt/my-project/.": Permission denied (13)
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/opt/my-project/file1.so": Permission denied (13)
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/opt/my-project/file2.so": Permission denied (13)
...
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/opt/my-project/file420.so" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
...
sent 71,147 bytes  received 53,278 bytes  49,770.00 bytes/sec
total size is 314,634,345  speedup is 2,528.71
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1330) [sender=3.2.4dev]
```

What's causing this behavior?

Rsync and OS versions:

- Local: Windows 11, CygWin/rsync  version 3.2.4dev  protocol version 31
- Remote: Ubuntu 20.04, rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the default rsync that comes with CygWin doesn't seem to be compatible with remote Linux filesystems. The solution was to install rsync from here: https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/CygSSH

By using this, everything works as expected.